# Creating Dynamic Javascript Proxies on MVC/WebApi

Tags: javascript, c#, dynamic, proxy

I used Asp.net Boilerplate (ABP) on a recent project, and was impressed by how they transform services into javascript in a completely transparent, almost magical way.

I'm digging through their code in attempt to replicate just that part on a new project, instead of using everything. It does look rather complex though, so I was wondering if anybody has knowledge of how to do this (not necessarily in the ABP way).

Simply put, when you have a class like this (on your MVC/WebApi asp.net project):

```
public interface ITaskAppService : IApplicationService
{
    GetTasksOutput GetTasks(GetTasksInput input);
    void UpdateTask(UpdateTaskInput input);
    void CreateTask(CreateTaskInput input);
}
```

And make this call:

```
Configuration.Modules.AbpWebApi().DynamicApiControllerBuilder.For<ITaskAppService>("tasksystem/task").Build();
```

You can do this in your JS:

```
abp.services.tasksystem.task.getTasks({
    state: 1
}).done(function (result) {
    //use result.tasks here...
});
```

There is more information on the uses on their webpage: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/v1.5.2/Dynamic-Web-API

Comment: I don't know much of C# but in Java you can use reflection.

Comment: Yes, I know he uses reflection. Still that leaves me nowhere closer to the solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the JavaScript Create-Update-Delete actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49204884/how-does-the-javascript-create-update-delete-actually-work)

Comment: Do you found any solution? "abp generate-proxy" cli command is awsome